# Passing limited queryset to related_to() in django-tagging

Tags: django, django-queryset, tagging

I want to use the `related_to()` function in django-tagging and I am passing a queryset looking like this:

```
Chapter.objects.all().order_by('?')[:5]  #the important thing here is the "[:5]"
```

My problem is that this function apparently uses the `in_bunk()` function and you `Cannot use 'limit' or 'offset' with in_bulk`

How can I restrict my queryset to only pass 5 objects and at the same time make use of in_bunk?

I know that related_to() lets you pass the variable `num` (which is the number of objects it should return) but I don't want it to output the same queryset every single time. So i came up with the idea of ordering it randomly and limiting it *before* it was passed to the function. But as you can see: limited querysets and bunk_it doesn't go hand in hand very well.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution though it wasn't the best and though it processes unnecessary data. I simply run through all instances of the model related to the current instance and I then sort randomly and slice afterwards:

```
related_objects = instance.related_to(Model)        # all related objects are found
related_objects = random.sample(related_objects,5)  # .. and afterwards sorted randomly and sliced
```